# Discord.py Move Members Permission

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm making a discord bot and it has a move command that moves all the members in a voice channel to another, well the main problem is this command should only work for those with move members permission but it does not! It doesn't work even if the user has that permission and it always show me an error. Here is the code:

```
def in_voice_channel():
    def predicate(ctx):
        return ctx.author.voice and ctx.author.voice.channel
    return check(predicate)

@in_voice_channel()
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(move_members=True)
async def moveall(ctx, *, channel : discord.VoiceChannel):
    author_ch = ctx.author.voice.channel.mention
    for members in ctx.author.voice.channel.members:
        await members.move_to(channel)
    await ctx.send(f'Moved everyone in {author_ch} to {channel.mention}!')
```

Comment: What error does it show?

Comment: Sorry for late response `You are missing Move Members permission(s) to run this command.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in this code is not with the permissions setup.
`@commands.has_permissions(move_members=True)` is the way to go.

What is the use of `@in_voice_channel()` decorator?
As far as I know this is not from discord.py

## Update

After testing it myself, even though "Move Members" is the right permission to go for depending on [discord.py docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.has_permissions), it does not seem to work properly.

You can instead use another check like `@commands.has_role()` to make this work or wait until the bug gets fixed.

Comment: `You are missing Move Members permission(s) to run this command.` this is the error that i'm getting

Comment: i edited the question you can check it out

Comment: Then I'm guessing that the problem has to do with Discord permissions.

Answer (score 0):

`@commands.has_permissions()` checks the channel permissions, and text channels do not have move_members or mute_members permissions.

What you are looking for is `@commands.has_guild_permissions()` which checks to see if that user has server wide permissions to move/mute members.

This means that to check if the user has `move_member` you will need to put `@commands.has_guild_permissions(move_members=True)` before your function/command.